# Sugarcrm: change icon of module

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I've created a module in sugarcrm of type basic. I now want to change the icon of it from the default icon to something custom. I read tons of forum posts about how to do it, varying from placing new icons in custom/themes/default/images/ or in themes/mytheme/images/, but none of them is saying what I should name those images to get them picked up.

Any ideas?

I'm using Version 6.5.15 (Build 1083)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For custom SugarCRM modules, the icon files will be automatically created and placed in `/custom/themes/default/images`

Four icon files are created per module. For example module 'MyModule' those file names (and image sizes) will be:

1. CreateMyModule.gif (16x16)
2. icon_MyModule_32.png (32x32)
3. icon_MyModule_bar_32.png (32x32)
4. MyModule.gif (16x16)

If you'd like to replace these images, do so by dropping your own image of the same size and file name in the place of the existing file. Be sure that your file permissions are correct.